# How can i know which button is clicked? Objective C

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, button, action

I am doing Presence1 in Assignment which require me builds a multiple screens application.
I have two ViewController, vc1 and vc2. In vc1, i have two buttons. I use a same method for them and the title of them are same.

My question is How can i know which button is clicked in vc1 when i change to vc2?

There are a topic show me that I should get positions (x,y) of mouse when i click on button, but i think it is not quite good.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above would work. If you don't want to keep outlets for the buttons you can assign them tags in interface builder. As an example, you assign button 1 a tag value of 1 and button 2 a tag value of 2. Then in the code

```
-(void)onButtonClick:(id)sender {
    if(sender.tag == 1) {
        //respond to button 1
    } else if(sender.tag == 2) {
        //respond to button 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it's very simple. I didn't know that. But there was something wrong, i received a error : "Request for member 'tag' in something not a structure or union". Do i have to do something else?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that, since sender is an id, you can't use property notation. use [sender tag] instead or change the signature to -(void) onButtonClick:(UIButton*) sender.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two `NSButton` properties such as:

```
@interface ViewControllerOne : NSViewController
{
    NSButton *goButton;
    NSButton *stopButton;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSButton *goButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSButton *stopButton;

-(void)onButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then you can compare the sender with the button pointer:

```
-(void)onButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    if (sender == goButton) {
    }

    else if (sender == stopButton) {
    }
}
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Oh, if i replace NSButton with UIButton, it will be ok? There are some problems...

Comment: The example above should be very similar with regards to Cocoa (Mac SDK) and Cocoa touch (iPhone SDK)